# Multiple UITableViewCells doing different things when tapped

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, automatic-ref-counting

I have a `UITableView` with 5 cells. When each are tapped, they do different things. But for now (in order for the code to not be too long), when tapped, they all call out a `NSLog`.

Here is the code.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UITableViewCell *newCell = [_randomCells cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    if ([(newCell) isEqualToString:@"Random cell 1"]) {
        NSLog(@"foo bar 1.");
    } else if ([(newCell) isEqualToString:@"Random cell 2"]) {
        NSLog(@"foo bar 2.");
    } else if ([(newCell) isEqualToString:@"Random cell 3"]) {
        NSLog(@"foo bar 3.");
    } else if ([(newCell) isEqualToString:@"Random cell 4"]) {
        NSLog(@"foo bar 4.");
    } else if ([(newCell) isEqualToString:@"Random cell 5"]) {
        NSLog(@"foo bar 5.");
    }
}
```

I figured that this would be the most appropriate way to detect tapped `UITableViewCell`s with Storyboards since I couldn't find another way to do it.

In all five if statements, however, I receive this error message:

```
No visible @interface for 'UITableViewCell' declares the selector 'isEqualToString:'
```

How would I fix this issue? Thanks in advance.

Please note, I am using typing the code with Objective-C ARC and using Storyboards.

Comment: Usually, you would do this by using the indexPath.row, not by looking at the text in the cell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you are checking for the text that displays in the cell?  If so, you need the `textLabel` property.

Try this:

```
[newCell.textLabel.text isEqualToString:@"Random cell 1"]
```

Good Luck!

Comment: It didm't work, but only because `.text` wasn't added at the end of `newCell.textLabel`. It's working now and I'll still mark it as correct. Thank you again.

Comment: I edited to reflect this so the code is usable, sorry for the oversight, I was going from memory :)

Answer (score 0):

you can detect tapped UITableViewCell  by using indexpath...

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (indexPath.row==0 ) 
        NSLog(@"foo bar 1.");
     else if (indexPath.row==1)
        NSLog(@"foo bar 2.");
    else if (indexPath.row==2)
        NSLog(@"foo bar 3.");
    else if (indexPath.row==3) 
        NSLog(@"foo bar 4.");
    else if (indexPath.row==4) 
        NSLog(@"foo bar 5.");
}
```